# How can a Z80 assembly program find out the address stored in the SP register?

Tags: assembly, z80

I'm wondering how to write a program in Z80 assembler that discovers the value stored in the SP register.

From what I've seen, the only instructions that touch the SP register are:

- `LD SP, HL/IX/IY`
- `EX (SP), HL/IX/IY`
- `PUSH / POP`

However, none of them seem to load the address stored in the SP register anywhere. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Incidentally, the Z-80 also has `LD SP,nn`, `LD SP,(mem)` and `LD (mem),SP`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The standard way would be adding it to HL. After clearing HL that is.

```
    LD  HL,0
    ADD HL,SP
```

Voila.

This is not only already available with the 8080,

```
    DAD  SP   ; Same opcode (39h), same workings
```

thus preferable, but as well very handy when setting up a pointer to parameters on stack as, of course, any other constant than 0 can be used and added.

Now, the Z80 did in addition bring a way to store SP with the ED group:

```
    LD  (loc),SP
```

With 4 bytes (ED 73 ll hh) it's as long as the LD/ADD sequence and only one T-cycle faster (20 vs. 21) while restricting the store to a fixed address, which may not be always handy - accessing SP is quite often done during task switch or alike where hard coded addresses are a bad idea.

Comment: Great, I didn't realized that I could add SP. Thanks!